# JS SyntaxError: Identifier ' ' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, variables, let

So I have this file that is giving me errors in my console of being defined already. I have searched all throughout and this is the only file in my server that even mentions **DataEntries**. It is mentioned 10 times in this file but only defined 1 time despite the console saying it was already declared. Maybe I'm missing something, if someone can find where **DataEntries** is being declared twice? I've tried to switch it to var instead of let but that gives me more errors and I've had other scripts like this one work fine with let.

Edit - Also I've tried changing the variable to something else like let test = 0 and it will change and say test has already been declared. So it seems like it's something with the first variable no matter what.

```
/*

    Variables

*/

let DataEntries = 0;

/*

    Functions

*/

function makeid(length) {
  var result = "";
  var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghikjlmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //abcdef
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}

async function GenerateInformation(pSource, pCid, pItemID, pItemData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (pItemID == "") return resolve("{}");

    let returnInfo = "{}";

    if (!isNaN(pItemID)) {
      returnInfo = JSON.stringify({
        serial: makeid(3) + "-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999 + 1),
        ammo: 0,
      });

      return resolve(returnInfo);
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(pItemID) === "[object String]") {
      switch (pItemID.toLowerCase()) {
        case "idcard":
          if (pItemData.fake) {
            returnInfo = JSON.stringify(pItemData);

            return resolve(returnInfo);
          } else {
            let gender = "Male";
            if (exports["llrp-base"].getChar(pSource, "gender") === 1) {
              gender = "Female";
            }

            returnInfo = JSON.stringify({
              ["ID"]: pCid,
              ["Nome"]: exports["llrp-base"]
                .getChar(pSource, "first_name")
                .replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ""),
              ["Sobrenome"]: exports["llrp-base"]
                .getChar(pSource, "last_name")
                .replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ""),
              ["Sexo"]: gender,
              ["Data de Nascimento"]: exports["llrp-base"].getChar(
                pSource,
                "dob"
              ),
            });

            return resolve(returnInfo);
          }
        case "pdbadge":
          exports.oxmysql.query(
            `SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, c.job, (CASE WHEN m.image IS NULL THEN "0" ELSE m.image END) AS image, gr.name AS rank_name, (CASE WHEN j.callsign IS NULL THEN "000" ELSE j.callsign END) AS callsign FROM characters c INNER JOIN groups_members gm ON (gm.cid = c.id AND gm.group = c.job) INNER JOIN groups_ranks gr ON (gr.group = c.job AND gr.rank = gm.rank) LEFT JOIN mdt_profiles m ON m.cid = c.id LEFT JOIN jobs_callsigns j ON (j.cid = c.id AND j.job = c.job) WHERE c.id = '${pCid}'`,
            [],
            function (result) {
              returnInfo = JSON.stringify({
                ["_hideKeys"]: ["image", "job"],
                ["Nome"]: result[0].first_name.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ""),
                ["Sobrenome"]: result[0].last_name.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ""),
                ["Rank"]: result[0].rank_name,
                ["Callsign"]: result[0].callsign,
                ["image"]: result[0].image,
                ["job"]: result[0].job,
              });

              return resolve(returnInfo);
            }
          );
          break;
        default:
          if (pItemData === undefined) {
            pItemData = {};
          }

          returnInfo = JSON.stringify(pItemData);

          return resolve(returnInfo);
      }
    } else {
      return resolve(returnInfo);
    }
  });
}

/*

    Events

*/

onNet("onResourceStart", (resource) => {
  if (resource == GetCurrentResourceName()) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      emit("llrp-inventory:luaItemList", itemList);
    }, 5000);
  }
});

onNet("SpawnEventsServer", async () => {
  let src = source;

  emitNet(
    "requested-dropped-items",
    src,
    JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, DroppedInventories))
  );
});

onNet("server-request-update", async (pCid) => {
  let src = source;
  let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

  let inventoryPlayer = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
    `SELECT count(item_id) as amount, id, name, item_id, information, slot, dropped, creationDate FROM inventory where name= '${playerInventoryName}' group by slot`
  );

  if (inventoryPlayer) {
    emitNet("inventory-update-player", src, [
      inventoryPlayer,
      0,
      playerInventoryName,
    ]);
  }
});

onNet("server-request-update-src", async (pCid, pSource) => {
  let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

  let inventoryPlayer = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
    `SELECT count(item_id) as amount, id, name, item_id, information, slot, dropped, creationDate FROM inventory where name= '${playerInventoryName}' group by slot`
  );

  if (inventoryPlayer) {
    emitNet("inventory-update-player", pSource, [
      inventoryPlayer,
      0,
      playerInventoryName,
    ]);
  }
});

onNet(
  "server-inventory-open",
  async (
    pCoords,
    pCid,
    pSecondInventory,
    pTargetName,
    pItemToDropArray,
    pSource,
    pWeight,
    pSlots
  ) => {
    let src = source;

    if (!src) {
      src = pSource;
    }

    let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

    if (
      InUseInventories[pTargetName] ||
      InUseInventories[playerInventoryName]
    ) {
      if (InUseInventories[playerInventoryName]) {
        if (InUseInventories[playerInventoryName] != pCid) {
          return;
        }
      }
      if (InUseInventories[pTargetName]) {
        if (InUseInventories[pTargetName] != pCid) {
          pSecondInventory = "69";
        }
      }
    }

    let inventoryPlayer = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
      `SELECT count(item_id) as amount, id, name, item_id, information, slot, dropped, creationDate FROM inventory where name= '${playerInventoryName}' group by slot`
    );

    if (inventoryPlayer) {
      InUseInventories[playerInventoryName] = pCid;

      if (pSecondInventory == "1") {
        let inventoryTarget = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
          `SELECT count(item_id) as amount, id, name, item_id, information, slot, dropped, creationDate FROM inventory WHERE name = '${pTargetName}' group by slot`
        );

        if (inventoryTarget) {
          emitNet("inventory-open-target", src, [
            inventoryPlayer,
            0,
            playerInventoryName,
            inventoryTarget,
            0,
            pTargetName,
            500,
            true,
            pWeight,
            pSlots,
          ]);
          InUseInventories[pTargetName] = pCid;
        }
      } else if (pSecondInventory == "3") {
        let NewDroppedName = "Drop-" + DataEntries.toString();

        DataEntries = DataEntries + 1;

        DroppedInventories[NewDroppedName] = {
          position: {
            x: pCoords[0],
            y: pCoords[1],
            z: pCoords[2],
          },
          name: NewDroppedName,
          used: false,
          lastUpdated: Date.now(),
        };

        InUseInventories[NewDroppedName] = pCid;

        emitNet("inventory-open-target", src, [
          inventoryPlayer,
          0,
          playerInventoryName,
          "{}",
          0,
          NewDroppedName,
          500,
          false,
        ]);
      } else if (pSecondInventory == "13") {
        let NewDroppedName = "Drop-" + DataEntries.toString();

        DataEntries = DataEntries + 1;

        for (let Key in pItemToDropArray) {
          for (let i = 0; i < pItemToDropArray[Key].length; i++) {
            let objectToDrop = pItemToDropArray[Key][i];
            exports.oxmysql.query(
              `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${
                i + 1
              }', name='${NewDroppedName}', dropped='1' WHERE name='${Key}' and slot='${
                objectToDrop.faultySlot
              }' and item_id='${objectToDrop.faultyItem}'`
            );
          }
        }

        DroppedInventories[NewDroppedName] = {
          position: {
            x: pCoords[0],
            y: pCoords[1],
            z: pCoords[2],
          },
          name: NewDroppedName,
          used: false,
          lastUpdated: Date.now(),
        };

        emitNet(
          "Inventory-Dropped-Addition",
          -1,
          DroppedInventories[NewDroppedName]
        );
      } else if (pSecondInventory == "42069") {
        let NewDroppedName = "Drop-" + DataEntries.toString();

        DataEntries = DataEntries + 1;

        DroppedInventories[NewDroppedName] = {
          position: {
            x: pCoords[0],
            y: pCoords[1],
            z: pCoords[2],
          },
          name: NewDroppedName,
          used: true,
          lastUpdated: Date.now(),
        };

        emitNet(
          "Inventory-Dropped-Addition",
          -1,
          DroppedInventories[NewDroppedName]
        );

        let creationDate = Date.now();
        let information = "{}";

        if (pItemToDropArray.generateInformation || pItemToDropArray.data) {
          information = await GenerateInformation(
            src,
            pCid,
            pItemToDropArray.itemid,
            pItemToDropArray.data
          );
        }

        exports.oxmysql.insert(
          `INSERT INTO inventory (item_id, name, information, slot, dropped, creationDate) VALUES ('${pItemToDropArray.itemid}','${NewDroppedName}','${information}','${pItemToDropArray.slot}', '1', '${creationDate}' );`
        );
      } else if (shopList[pSecondInventory]) {
        var shopArray = shopList[pSecondInventory];
        var shopAmount = shopArray.length;

        shopArray.forEach(function (item, index) {
          item["id"] = 0;
          item["name"] = pTargetName;
          item["information"] = "{}";
          item["slot"] = index + 1;
        });

        emitNet("inventory-open-target", src, [
          inventoryPlayer,
          0,
          playerInventoryName,
          JSON.stringify(shopArray),
          shopAmount,
          pTargetName,
          500,
          false,
          false,
          false,
          pSecondInventory,
        ]);
      } else if (pSecondInventory == "7") {
        pItemToDropArray = JSON.parse(pItemToDropArray);

        let shopArray = [];

        shopArray[0] = {
          item_id: pItemToDropArray[0].itemid,
          id: 0,
          name: "shop",
          information: "{}",
          slot: 1,
          amount: pItemToDropArray[0].amount,
        };

        shopArray = JSON.stringify(shopArray);

        var shopAmount = pItemToDropArray.length;

        emitNet("inventory-open-target", src, [
          inventoryPlayer,
          0,
          playerInventoryName,
          shopArray,
          shopAmount,
          pTargetName,
          500,
          false,
        ]);
      } else {
        emitNet("inventory-update-player", src, [
          inventoryPlayer,
          0,
          playerInventoryName,
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
);

onNet("server-inventory-refresh", async (pCid, pSource) => {
  let src = source;

  if (!src) {
    src = pSource;
  }

  let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

  let inventoryPlayer = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
    `SELECT count(item_id) as amount, id, name, item_id, information, slot, dropped, creationDate FROM inventory where name= '${playerInventoryName}' group by slot`
  );

  if (inventoryPlayer) {
    emitNet("inventory-update-player", src, [
      inventoryPlayer,
      0,
      playerInventoryName,
    ]);
    emitNet("current-items", src, inventoryPlayer);
  }
});

onNet("server-inventory-close", async (pCid, pTargetInventoryName) => {
  let src = source;

  if (pTargetInventoryName.startsWith("Trunk")) {
    emitNet("toggle-animation", src, false);
  }

  InUseInventories = InUseInventories.filter((item) => item != pCid);

  if (
    pTargetInventoryName.indexOf("Drop") > -1 &&
    DroppedInventories[pTargetInventoryName]
  ) {
    if (DroppedInventories[pTargetInventoryName].used === false) {
      delete DroppedInventories[pTargetInventoryName];
    } else {
      let inventoryTarget = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
        `SELECT count(item_id) as amount, item_id, name, information, slot, dropped FROM inventory WHERE name='${pTargetInventoryName}' group by item_id `
      );

      if (
        inventoryTarget &&
        inventoryTarget.length == 0 &&
        DroppedInventories[pTargetInventoryName]
      ) {
        delete DroppedInventories[pTargetInventoryName];
        emitNet("Inventory-Dropped-Remove", -1, [pTargetInventoryName]);
      }
    }
  }

  emit("server-request-update-src", pCid, src);
});

onNet("server-inventory-move", async (pCid, pData, pCoords) => {
  let src = source;

  let targetslot = pData[0];
  let startslot = pData[1];
  let targetName = pData[2].replace(/"/g, "");
  let startname = pData[3].replace(/"/g, "");
  let purchase = pData[4];
  let itemCosts = pData[5];
  let itemidsent = pData[6];
  let itemmeta = pData[7];
  let amount = pData[8];
  let crafting = pData[9];
  let isWeapon = pData[10];
  let PlayerStore = pData[11];
  let shopId = pData[12];
  let creationDate = Date.now();

  if (
    (targetName.indexOf("Drop") > -1 || targetName.indexOf("hidden") > -1) &&
    DroppedInventories[targetName]
  ) {
    if (DroppedInventories[targetName].used === false) {
      DroppedInventories[targetName] = {
        position: {
          x: pCoords[0],
          y: pCoords[1],
          z: pCoords[2],
        },
        name: targetName,
        used: true,
        lastUpdated: Date.now(),
      };

      emitNet("Inventory-Dropped-Addition", -1, DroppedInventories[targetName]);
    }
  }

  let info = "{}";

  if (purchase) {
    info = await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, itemidsent);

    exports["llrp-financials"].updateCash(src, "-", itemCosts);

    let baseprice = itemList[itemidsent].price;
    exports["llrp-financials"].addTaxFromValue("Goods", baseprice);

    if (PlayerStore) {
      exports.oxmysql.query(
        `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${targetslot}', name='${targetName}', dropped='0' WHERE slot='${startslot}' and name='${startname}'`
      );
    } else if (crafting) {
      for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(amount); i++) {
        info - (await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, itemidsent));
        exports.oxmysql.query(
          `INSERT INTO inventory (item_id, name, information, slot, creationDate) VALUES ('${itemidsent}','${targetName}','${info}','${targetslot}','${creationDate}');`
        );
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(amount); i++) {
        info - (await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, itemidsent));
        exports.oxmysql.query(
          `INSERT INTO inventory (item_id, name, information, slot, creationDate) VALUES ('${itemidsent}','${targetName}','${info}','${targetslot}','${creationDate}');`
        );
      }
    }
  } else if (crafting == true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(amount); i++) {
      info - (await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, itemidsent));
      exports.oxmysql.query(
        `INSERT INTO inventory (item_id, name, information, slot, creationDate) VALUES ('${itemidsent}','${targetName}','${info}','${targetslot}','${creationDate}');`
      );
    }
  } else {
    let dropped = 0;
    if (targetName.indexOf("Drop") > -1 || targetName.indexOf("hidden") > -1) {
      dropped = 1;
    }

    exports.oxmysql.query(
      `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${targetslot}', name='${targetName}', dropped='${dropped}' WHERE slot='${startslot}' and name='${startname}'`
    );
  }
});

onNet("server-inventory-stack", async (pCid, pData, pCoords) => {
  let src = source;

  let targetslot = pData[0];
  let moveAmount = pData[1];
  let targetName = pData[2].replace(/"/g, "");
  let originSlot = pData[3];
  let originInventory = pData[4].replace(/"/g, "");
  let purchase = pData[5];
  let itemCosts = pData[6];
  let itemidsent = pData[7];
  let itemmeta = pData[8];
  let amount = pData[9];
  let crafting = pData[10];
  let isWeapon = pData[11];
  let PlayerStore = pData[12];
  let amountRemaining = pData[13];
  let shopId = pData[14];
  let creationDate = Date.now();

  if (
    (targetName.indexOf("Drop") > -1 || targetName.indexOf("hidden") > -1) &&
    DroppedInventories[targetName]
  ) {
    if (DroppedInventories[targetName].used === false) {
      DroppedInventories[targetName] = {
        position: {
          x: pCoords[0],
          y: pCoords[1],
          z: pCoords[2],
        },
        name: targetName,
        used: true,
        lastUpdated: Date.now(),
      };

      emitNet("Inventory-Dropped-Addition", -1, DroppedInventories[targetName]);
    }
  }

  let info = "{}";

  if (purchase) {
    info = await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, itemidsent);

    let cid = parseInt(targetName.replace("ply-", ""));
    let accountId = shopAccounts[shopId];
    let baseprice = itemList[itemidsent].price;
    let itemname = itemList[itemidsent].displayname;
    let comment = "Brought " + amount + " " + itemname;

    exports["llrp-financials"].updateCash(src, "-", itemCosts);
    exports["llrp-financials"].updateBalance(accountId, "+", itemCosts);
    exports["llrp-financials"].transaction(
      accountId,
      accountId,
      baseprice,
      comment,
      cid,
      7
    );
    exports["llrp-financials"].addTaxFromValue("Goods", baseprice);

    if (PlayerStore) {
      payStore(startname, itemCosts, itemidsent);

      exports.oxmysql.query(
        `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${targetslot}', name='${targetname}', dropped = '0' WHERE slot='${startslot}' AND name='${startname}'`
      );
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(amount); i++) {
        info = await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, itemidsent);
        exports.oxmysql.query(
          `INSERT INTO inventory (item_id, name, information, slot, creationDate) VALUES ('${itemidsent}','${targetName}','${info}','${targetslot}','${creationDate}');`
        );
      }
    }
  } else if (crafting) {
    for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(amount); i++) {
      info = await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, itemidsent);
      exports.oxmysql.query(
        `INSERT INTO inventory (item_id, name, information, slot, creationDate) VALUES ('${itemidsent}','${targetName}','${info}','${targetslot}','${creationDate}');`
      );
    }
  } else {
    if (amountRemaining > 0) {
      moveAmount = moveAmount + 1;
    }

    let inventory = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
      `SELECT id, item_id, creationDate FROM inventory WHERE slot='${originSlot}' and name='${originInventory}' LIMIT ${moveAmount}`
    );

    if (inventory) {
      let toupdate = 0;
      let itemids = "0";

      inventory.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (amountRemaining > 0 && index == inventory.length - 1) {
          toupdate = item.creationDate;
        } else {
          itemids = itemids + "," + item.id;
        }
      });

      let dropped = 0;
      if (
        targetName.indexOf("Drop") > -1 ||
        targetName.indexOf("hidden") > -1
      ) {
        dropped = 1;
      }

      let affectedRows = await exports.oxmysql.update_async(
        `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${targetslot}', name='${targetName}', dropped='${dropped}' WHERE id IN (${itemids})`
      );

      if (toupdate != 0) {
        emitNet(
          "inventory:qualityUpdate",
          src,
          originSlot,
          originInventory,
          toupdate
        );
      }
    }
  }
});

onNet("server-inventory-swap", async (pCid, pData, pCoords) => {
  let targetslot = pData[0];
  let targetname = pData[1].replace(/"/g, "");
  let startslot = pData[2];
  let startname = pData[3].replace(/"/g, "");

  let inventoryTarget = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
    `SELECT id FROM inventory WHERE slot='${targetslot}' AND name='${targetname}'`
  );

  if (inventoryTarget) {
    var itemids = "0";
    for (let i = 0; i < inventoryTarget.length; i++) {
      itemids = itemids + "," + inventoryTarget[i].id;
    }

    let string = "";
    if (targetname.indexOf("Drop") > -1 || targetname.indexOf("hidden") > -1) {
      string = `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${targetslot}', name ='${targetname}', dropped='1' WHERE slot='${startslot}' AND name='${startname}'`;
    } else {
      string = `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${targetslot}', name ='${targetname}', dropped='0' WHERE slot='${startslot}' AND name='${startname}'`;
    }

    let affectedRows = await exports.oxmysql.update_async(string);

    if (affectedRows && affectedRows > 0) {
      if (startname.indexOf("Drop") > -1 || startname.indexOf("hidden") > -1) {
        exports.oxmysql.update(
          `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${startslot}', name='${startname}', dropped='1' WHERE id IN (${itemids})`
        );
      } else {
        exports.oxmysql.update(
          `UPDATE inventory SET slot='${startslot}', name='${startname}', dropped='0' WHERE id IN (${itemids})`
        );
      }
    }
  }
});

onNet("server-update-item", async (pCid, pItemID, pSlot, pData) => {
  let src = source;

  let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

  let affectedRows = await exports.oxmysql.update_async(
    `UPDATE inventory SET information='${JSON.stringify(
      pData
    )}' WHERE item_id='${pItemID}' and name='${playerInventoryName}' and slot='${pSlot}'`
  );

  if (affectedRows && affectedRows > 0) {
    emit("server-request-update-src", pCid, src);
  }
});

onNet("server-update-item-id", async (pCid, pId, pData) => {
  let src = source;

  let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

  let affectedRows = await exports.oxmysql.update_async(
    `UPDATE inventory SET information='${JSON.stringify(
      pData
    )}' WHERE id='${pId}' and name='${playerInventoryName}'`
  );

  if (affectedRows && affectedRows > 0) {
    emit("server-request-update-src", pCid, src);
  }
});

onNet(
  "server-inventory-give",
  async (
    pCid,
    pItemID,
    pSlot,
    pAmount,
    pGenerateInfo,
    pItemData,
    pOpenedInv
  ) => {
    let src = source;

    let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;
    let information = "{}";
    let creationDate = Date.now();

    if (pGenerateInfo || pItemData) {
      information = await GenerateInformation(src, pCid, pItemID, pItemData);
    }

    let values = `('${playerInventoryName}','${pItemID}','${information}','${pSlot}','${creationDate}')`;
    if (pAmount > 1) {
      for (let i = 2; i <= pAmount; i++) {
        values =
          values +
          `,('${playerInventoryName}','${pItemID}','${information}','${pSlot}','${creationDate}')`;
      }
    }

    let insertId = await exports.oxmysql.insert_async(
      `INSERT INTO inventory (name,item_id,information,slot,creationDate) VALUES ${values};`
    );

    if (insertId && insertId > 0) {
      emit("server-request-update-src", pCid, src);
    }
  }
);

onNet("server-remove-item", async (pCid, pItemID, pAmount, pOpenedInv) => {
  let src = exports["llrp-base"].getSidWithCid(pCid);

  let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

  exports.oxmysql.query(
    `DELETE FROM inventory WHERE name='${playerInventoryName}' and item_id='${pItemID}' LIMIT ${pAmount}`,
    {},
    function () {
      if (src != 0) {
        emit("server-request-update-src", pCid, src);
      }
    }
  );
});

onNet("server-inventory-remove-slot", async (pCid, pItemID, pAmount, pSlot) => {
  let src = exports["llrp-base"].getSidWithCid(pCid);

  let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

  exports.oxmysql.query(
    `DELETE FROM inventory WHERE name='${playerInventoryName}' and item_id='${pItemID}' and slot='${pSlot}' LIMIT ${pAmount}`,
    {},
    function () {
      if (src != 0) {
        emit("server-request-update-src", pCid, src);
      }
    }
  );
});

onNet(
  "server-remove-item-kv",
  async (pCid, pItemID, pAmount, pMetaKey, pMetaValue) => {
    let src = exports["llrp-base"].getSidWithCid(pCid);

    let playerInventoryName = "ply-" + pCid;

    let inventory = await exports.oxmysql.query_async(
      `SELECT id, information FROM inventory WHERE item_id='${pItemID}' AND name='${playerInventoryName}'`
    );

    if (inventory) {
      let itemids = "0";

      for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
        let meta = JSON.parse(inventory[i].information);

        if (meta[pMetaKey] == pMetaValue) {
          itemids = itemids + "," + inventory[i].id;
        }
      }

      exports.oxmysql.query(
        `DELETE FROM inventory WHERE id IN (${itemids}) LIMIT ${pAmount}`,
        {},
        function () {
          if (src != 0) {
            emit("server-request-update-src", pCid, src);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
);

onNet("inventory:degItem", async (pItemId, pPercent, pItemClass, pCid) => {
  if (
    itemList[pItemClass.toString()] == null ||
    itemList[pItemClass.toString()].decayrate <= 0.0
  ) {
    return;
  }

  let percent = Math.round(
    ((TimeAllowed * itemList[pItemClass.toString()].decayrate) / 100) * pPercent
  );

  exports.oxmysql.query(
    `UPDATE inventory set creationDate = creationDate - ${percent} WHERE id = ${pItemId}`
  );
});

onNet("llrp-inventory:clear", async (pSource, pName) => {
  let src = source;

  if (pSource) {
    src = pSource;
  }

  let cid = 0;
  let name = "";
  if (!pName) {
    cid = exports["llrp-base"].getChar(src, "id");
    if (!cid) {
      return;
    }

    name = "ply-" + cid;
  } else {
    name = pName;
  }

  exports.oxmysql.query(
    `DELETE FROM inventory WHERE name='${name}'`,
    {},
    function () {
      if (cid > 0) {
        emit("server-request-update-src", cid, src);

        exports.oxmysql.scalar(
          `SELECT cash FROM characters WHERE id = '${cid}'`,
          {},
          function (cash) {
            if (cash && cash > 0) {
              exports["llrp-financials"].updateCash(src, "-", cash);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Try debugging: first, rename `DataEntries` in this file to anything else, and then, `console.log(DataEntries)` - with any luck should find out what it actually is.

Comment: As soon as I change the first variable to anything else like let test = 0, and rerun it. The console just starts to say that test has already been declared. I followed by making it test = 0 and logging out DataEntries and it is now undefined. So no matter what it is that first variable giving me the issues @mbojko

Comment: How are you running the script? What environment? If it's running in the browser, are you  using `<script>` tags? In which case, do you have a duplicate entry for this file?

Comment: Refresh the page? Restart the script?